# Using the id attribute for readability purposes only?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I recently switched from normal class styling to tailwindcss.
And my code went from looking like this

`<div class="searchBox"></div>`

to this

`<div class="flex shadow-small bg-white rounded-small items-center px-1 py-1 ml-2 mt-2 w-60"></div>`

Previously, the class name allows me to immediately identify the content inside of the div.
However, now with Tailwind, I have to add comments in my HTML code to make my code more readable. I don't like that solution because I can't add comment directly into  tags. I've also tried using the id attribute for purely readability purposes, but I'm wary of duplicating ids.

Do you guys have any recommendations for this?

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with comments?

Perhaps just add the original class name to the new list? If a class name in the list doesnt appear in your css, it wont have any effect

```
<div class="searchBox flex shadow-small bg-white rounded-small items-center px-1 py-1 ml-2 mt-2 w-60"></div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion! With comments, if I put it inside the div, it will disappear when I collapse the div. If I put it outside of the div, it's hard to tell exactly which section of code this particular comment is talking about unless I add comments for every single div.
Adding the original class name to the new list is a decent solution, but imo I'd prefer the identifier(searchBox in this case) to be more visually distinct from the tailwind classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can define those classes into `searchBox` by using `@apply` in your base stylesheet, which one is added in `main.js` file.

[image]

I think this way will help you.